# Modulus altering variable values when it shouldn't

Tags: c, variables, while-loop, modulo

The modulus is altering the value of `primer` since when I print it before finding the modulus I get it's actual value but after finding modulus it turns to zero or one at times. It's a program that determines whether the number the user has entered is prime or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num;
int primer;
int mod;
printf("enter num> ");
scanf("%d", &num);
primer = num-1;
while(primer > 0){
    mod = num%primer;


    if(mod == 0){
        printf("not prime");
        break;}

    if(primer == 1){
        printf("prime");
        break;}
    
    
        primer--;}

}
```

Comment: What values are you inputting?  What result are you seeing? What result did you expect to get?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] -- the rest of your `while` loop is missing.

Comment: @G.M. I edited it in

Comment: Please use consistent readable formatting and indentation.  `primer--;}}`??? Really?  If you don't put the time in to make your code readable, not only will no one else read it, you won't be able to either.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i just started learning thanks for the tip but this is just a sinple script so I didn't see any need in formatting it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of blaming language constructs (especially well-defined mathematical ones) for problems.

The problem is your code. It does not do what you think it does. You are trying to accomplish your task using two competing methods. Start over. Count from 2 and up when you are looping over possible divisors. Your variable name choices are not helping you either.

Remember, the computer will not help you solve this task. As a programmer, your job is to first solve the task yourself, and only second to tell the computer how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Code fails with primes as it does `primer == 1` and then `mod == 0` is true - leading to "not prime".

```
mod = num%primer;
if (mod == 0) {
  printf("not prime");
  break;
}

// Too late
if (primer == 1) {
  printf("prime");
  break;
}
```

---

Code is inefficient as it makes O(num) tests.

---

Alternative, test with odd divisors: [3 ... square root of `num`] - that is  `divisor*divisor <= num`.

Use `divisor*divisor <= num` reformed as `divisor <= num/divisor` to avoid overflow.

```
int isprime(int num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    return num == 2; // Only even prime
  }
  for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= num/divisor; divisor += 2) {
    if (num%divisor == 0) {
      return 0;
    } 
  }
  // Reach this point when num is a prime or an odd less than 3
  return num >= 3;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't with the modulus at all seems like when `primer` reaches one the result for `num%primer` is 0 hence both conditions of the if statements are met seeing as to how `mod == 0` and `primer == 1` are both `true` , a simply switching the control flow to `if(primer == 1)` then `else if (mod == 0)` fixes it. As for the primer being one and zero at times that's also a classic case of my stupidity I was checking it's value within an `if` statement hence the value was it's value after it was reduced by the loop.

Comment: Don’t call yourself stupid. Remember, nothing is obvious until you have learned it. ;-)