# Prime number loop logic

Tags: c, for-loop, logic, nested-loops, primes

I wanted to ask you somthing that i cant understand why it works.
i need to make a code that you input some number and it gives you all the prime numbers until you get to that num.

now i have this code that does the trick.
like every number that is not prime it goes to the next n and checks it but i dont understand this
if like it gets 4 and then turns it to 5 the j wont go to 3? and then you start checking 5/3 but you miss the division by 2 and so on like i dont get it does it resets the j to 2 every time that i edd i+1?

also if i give it like 10 it prints 11 and i dont want it to pass the original number how do i do that.

int num;

```
printf("please enter num ");
scanf_s("%d", &num);
int i, j;
for (i = 2; i < num; i++)
{
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
    {

        printf("j=%d ", j);

        if (i % j == 0)
            i += 1;


    }
    printf("%d ", i);


}
```

Comment: Take a pen and paper and execute the code yourself line by line.

Comment: when i % j == 0, mean i is a non-prime (given that i & j are never equal because of the check in the inner loop). Hence there is no point in running rest of the inner loop for this value of i. You can't use a break in the inner loop as it will end up calling the second printf even for non-prime.

Comment: You can take look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/ for finding prime numbers in a range

Answer (score 2):

1. "code that does the trick" simply fails for various `num`.  Going to the next `i` (`if (i % j == 0) i += 1;`) fails as code needs to test against smaller `j` again with the new `i`.  Recommend forming a [helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69901580/2410359).

```
for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
  if (isprime(i)) printf("%d ", i);
}
```

2. [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a much better approach. [@NeilB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430322/prime-number-loop-logic/74433438#comment131396826_74430322)

Answer (score 0):

> now i have this code that does the trick

No, the algorithm is wrong.

This

```
int num;
printf("please enter num ");
scanf("%d", &num);
int i, j;
for (i = 2; i < num; i++)
{
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
    {    
        // commented out   printf("j=%d ", j);

        if (i % j == 0)
            i += 1;
    }
    printf("%d ", i);
}
```

with **input value 30** will give the output

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 27 29
```

but **27 is not a prime**

A few other values that the algo handles incorrect: 35, 87, 95

Comment: This declares the algorithm is wrong, (which could have just as easily been done in a comment.) but offers no clue how to make it right.

Comment: @ryyker Nope... that is an exact answer for the question... we ain't a free coding service